# How to add more than one button to a FadeTransition?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a program for school trying to create a vending machine and I’m trying to get more than one button to be a bake to do a fade transition off the same transition! Is this possible or do I have to have an entirely different fade transition for each button?

```
FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition();
ft.setNode(imgView1);
ft.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
ft.setFromValue(1.0);
ft.setToValue(0.0);
ft.setCycleCount(1);
ft.setAutoReverse(true);
ft.plat();

btn1.setOnMousePressed(e->ft.play());
```

I have 3 other buttons and images I want to do the same thing with but not sure if I have to make each Seperated FadeTransition or if I can add them to this one?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the nodes are the only ones in a common parent that has no visuals, you cannot apply the transition to more than one node.

You could however bind the `opacity` property of the other nodes to the `opacity` of the animated node:

```
node2.opacityProperty().bind(imgView1.opacityProperty());
node3.opacityProperty().bind(imgView1.opacityProperty());
```

---

You could also create a `Timeline` with a `KeyValue` element for every node:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                                              new KeyValue(node1.opacityProperty(), 1d),
                                              new KeyValue(node2.opacityProperty(), 1d),
                                              new KeyValue(node3.opacityProperty(), 1d)),
                                 new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5),
                                              new KeyValue(node1.opacityProperty(), 0d),
                                              new KeyValue(node2.opacityProperty(), 0d),
                                              new KeyValue(node3.opacityProperty(), 0d)));

timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
timeline.play();
```

Comment: I am still very new to this and not to sure how I would implement the Timeline and KeyValue. I have been trying to find how, but it’s is getting the best of me and leaving me clueless.

Comment: You simply define `KeyFrame`s which describe the desired state at a certain time in the animation or contain an event handler to be executed at that time. If you use `KeyValue`s, you pass a property and the value it should  have at at the time defined in it's `KeyFrame`. `Timeline` animates the property to reach this value at the given time. The code above the opacities start at 1 and reach 0 after 5 seconds.